# How to track down reason of suddenly appearing non-termination of a programme, while with `strace` it terminates?

Tags: strace, hang

I have a programme that suddenly started to not terminate (I was not updating the programme, but my system & the kernel, I do not remember what was causing the effect. Recompiling the programme did not change the non-terminating behaviour). Under `strace`, however, it does terminate.

How can such things be traced down?

### Concrete example:

Here is the concrete example where I encountered this )(for me) strange thing:

It is regarding [WWWOFFLE](http://gedanken.org.uk/software/wwwoffle/), [SVN revision](http://gedanken.org.uk/software/wwwoffle/#H_1_3_1) 2250 (latest at the time of investigating/ writing), compiled on Arch/ Artix Linux according to the [AUR-package](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/wwwoffle-svn/).

Since some time (no update of WWWOFFLE, but updates of system and
kernel, and after appearance of this problem recompilation of WWWOFFLE
without a noticable change) putting wwwoffle in online- or offline-mode
hangs quite often indefinitely. If I want to trace it down with
`strace`, it does not hang. If I wrap it in a shell-script it hangs with `strace`, but not with `strace -f`/ `strace -ff`.

#### Details:

1. start `wwwoffled` server:

   ```
   wwwoffled -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -f -d 6
   ```
2. put WWWOFFLE in online mode (switching from offline to online mode usually succeeds):

   ```
   wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -online
   ```

   Terminal output:

   ```
   WWWOFFLE Now Online
   ```

   and return to calling shell.
3. put WWWOFFLE in offline mode:

   ```
   wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -offline
   ```

   Terminal output:

   ```
   WWWOFFLE Now Offline
   ```

   and no termination.

   The log of `wwwoffled` accoring to number 1 says correctly `Important: WWWOFFLE Offline`.
   Aborting `wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -offline` with `<STRG>+<c>` and trying again now prints out correctly `WWWOFFLE Already Offline`, but also does not terminate.
4. switching to online mode while WWWOFFLE is already online does also
   not terminate:

   ```
   wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -online
   ```

   while WWWOFFLE is already online does correctly print out

   ```
   WWWOFFLE Already Online
   ```

   but does not terminate.
5. `strace`:

   ```
   strace wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -offline
   ```

   and

   ```
   strace wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -online
   ```

   does seem to always terminate when `wwwoffled` is started as in 1.
6. If I put `wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -offline` and`wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -online` in a bash script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   wwwoffle -c /etc/wwwoffle/wwwoffle.conf -offline
   ```

   and execute it, then also *with* `strace` it does not terminate:

   ```
   strace ./wwwoffle-off.sh
   ```

   prints out as the last lines

   ```
   [...]
   access("/usr/bin/wwwoffle", R_OK)       = 0
   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
   clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f36a75e1e50) = 6426
   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
   rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
   rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x5573f5295be0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f36a76898b0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f36a76898b0}, 8) = 0
   wait4(-1, WWWOFFLE Already Offline
   ```

   and waiting there forever. (Note that the `WWWOFFLE Already Offline` is the output from `wwwoffle` and is written to `stdout`, the last output from `strace`, written to `stderr`, is `wait4(-1,`)
7. With `strace -f` or `strace -ff` (which traces also forked child threads), it terminates again.

I see it only with WWWOFFLE, but it might not be a WWWOFFLE-problem. I
have no idea how to track it down. How can those things be tracked down, what might cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally a symptom of *something* going wrong within the software in *some* way, no general answer can be given.

So it is really specific to the bugs in the concrete software which shows such behaviour.

In the WWWOFFLE-case, listening to the network communication between `wwwoffle` and `wwwoffled` does reveal some information.